# regex replace string "-" and "/"

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i have a string like this for example: **`09223-2993/120029`**

i need to replace the `-` and `/` using regex

how can i do this ?

this is what i made, work replacing `-` , but i cant find a way to reaplce `/`:

```
    var test = $("#myvalue").val().split("");

    for(var i=0; i < test.length; i++) {
        test[i] = test[i].replace(/-/g, '');
    }

    value2 = test.join("" );

    alert(value2);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are really close, all you need to do is add `/` to your regex

You should just be able to do this:

```
 test[i] = test[i].replace(/[-/]/g, '');
```

since `-` is not special to regex, to use the `/` escape it with a backslash as above, or place it inside of `[]` to mean a character class.

Comment: `/` means "end of the regex", I think that constitutes "special".

Comment: @Kolink, you should've tried it before you down-voted it...  The suggested code works fine. `"asdf-/".replace(/[-/]/g, '');`

Comment: @Kolink Not if it is in a character class

Comment: @Kolink: `/` won't serve as regexp delimiter within the character class context (`[...]`). The original was fine.

Comment: "`-` is not special to regex" is not quite true; `-` it gains a special meaning within the character class if it is not the first or the last character in it (character range). It is the first character in the character class in this particular example, but generally speaking this is misinformation :p

Comment: Well colour me surprised... And there was me thinking that `/` were basically identical to `"` on strings, but for regexes instead. Un-downvoted. (Or it would be if I could... the vote is locked)

Comment: @Kolink - Tell him to edit the answer, and you can un-downvote it. :)

Comment: Added an HTML comment to the answer, so I could un-downvote :)

Answer (score 6):

To use a literal `/` in a regex, you must escape it. Write `\/` to do so.

Final script should look like:

```
var test = $("#myvalue").val().replace(/[-/]/g,'');
alert(test);
```

Your whole loop thing was completely unnecessary, so I remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, the loop was there because i was trying other ways to replace it. +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

The character `/` has a special meaning in regex (you know, it encloses it `/regex/modifiers`). Special characters have to be escaped with backslash `\`.

```
test[i].replace(/\//g, 'something');
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, you have to escape a slash as `\/`. However, it might be a more robust approach to remove all characters that are not digits:

```
test[i] = test[i].replace(/\D/g, '');
```

`\D` is the negated version of `\d`, i.e. not digit.

Answer (score 0):

This only leaves the value, which might be a lot less complex

```
var value = $("#myvalue").val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

alert(value);
```